# Core-Data Store Location on Device

Tags: ios, core-data, icloud

I am transitioning a app to iCloud support for core-data.  Prior to loading the NSMangagedObjectContext I like to access the meta data to determine the starting model version.  This tells me the starting state before any automatic model migration takes place so I can resolve any issue between version.  To get he meta data I have used:

```
NSDictionary *sourceMetadata = [NSPersistentStoreCoordinator metadataForPersistentStoreOfType:nil URL:storeURL error:&error];
```

My problem is with my core-data store in iCloud I don't know how to figure out the file URL on the device, I can see it in documents directory but I don't know how to get iOS to tell me the path.

Is there a way to get the file path or am I thinking about this wrong.

Comment: Please log a bug with Apple because they don't provide any way to perform this check or get the actual store filename without doing your own manual scan of files on disk to find the store file, and there may be multiple such files, depending on the iCloud account.

Answer (score 0):

Well since at least one person agrees this is not possible I have instead created NSPersistantStoreCoordinator without allowing migration than I pull the current model version out of the error that is created.  This works but seem like a backwards way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

With Core Data you *always* know where the store is, regardless of whether you're using iCloud. It's wherever you told Core Data to put it. With iCloud, Core Data writes transaction logs to the iCloud container, but the persistent store is still wherever you want it to be.

When you call `addPersistentStoreWithType:configuration:URL:options:error:` you provide a file URL that indicates the store's location. That's where it is. There's no iCloud magic to the store's location, it's wherever you put it. You probably made a call to `URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier:` before doing that, but that also gives you a normal file URL.

Comment: This is not the case in my experience.  The URL you give it becomes the root location for a file path that is long and changes based on the device and the user iCloud settings.